# jquery mobile nested list view not displaying submenus

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am working on incorporating a jquery mobile nested list view as the main navigation menu on the mobile version of a vBulletin site I am building. Please note that you will need to use a mobile device / emulator or the list view will not display. I am doing my testing by changing the user agent in Safari.

Here is a link to the site:

http://www.ulbf.innov-images.com/content.php?6-home

Here is the html with the listview:

```
<ul data-role="listview">    
    <li><a href="register.php">How to Join</a></li>
    <li><a href="memberlist.php">Find a Service or Member</a></li>
    <li><a href="sendmessage.php">Contact Us</a></li>                      
    <li>For Members
        <ul data-role="listview">
            <li><a href="#">History &amp; Mission</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Success Stories</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Current Officers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Past Events &amp; Topics</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The list item that contains the nested listview is the "For Members" item.

I have done quite a bit of research into this, and even created a jsfiddle with the same html and version of jquery/jq mobile.

EDIT: the jsfiddle does indeed work. That is the point. The fiddle works, but the code on my site doesn't and I can't figure out why.

http://jsfiddle.net/QfyZd/

My conclusion is that there must be other javascript and / or css in vbulletin that is preventing the submenu from displaying. I tried not including two of the vBulletin javascripts, but that had effect.

I'm not sure where to go from here.

EDIT - I figured out that the problem is coming from vbulletin-mobile.js. I unminified the file and loaded it to my server. It seems like the problem is occuring in the listview section in lines 799 - 1006. That is quite a few lines, and so far I am at a loss to figure out where. I will keep trying, but in the meantime if anyone has anyone idea, I would be grateful for help.

Comment: Your submenu in jsfiddle is working for me just fine

Comment: BTW you don't need to use `data-role="listview"` on a secondary list. You can also consider to use separate pages for submenus. It's not necessary, but you can get more control over appearance and behavior of your secondary listviews.

Comment: peterm is right, your jsFiddle example works just fine.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I was unclear about why I included the fiddle. The fiddle does indeed work, but similar code on my site does not work. I need help figuring out why it doesn't work on my site.

Answer (score 0):

**jquery mobile nested list view**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8'/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=no; target-densityDpi=device-dpi"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="index">
            <div data-theme="b" data-role="header">
                <h1>Index page</h1>
            </div>

            <div data-role="content">
                <ul data-role="listview" data-header-theme="e">
                    <li>Animals
                        <ul>
                            <li>Pets
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="index.html">Canary</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.html">Cat</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.html">Dog</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>Farm animals
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="index.html">Chicken</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.html">Cow</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.html">Sheep</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>Wild animals>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="index.html">Alligator</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.html">Bear</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.html">Zebra</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Colors
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="index.html">Blue</a></li>
                            <li><a href="index.html">Green</a></li>
                            <li><a href="index.html">Red</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Vehicles
                        <ul>
                            <li>Cars
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="index.html">Audi</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.html">BMW</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.html">Volkswagen</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li>Planes
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="index.html">Boeing</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.html">Embraer</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.html">Airbus</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul><br/><br/>
                <div data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="b" data-content-theme="d" data-inset="false">
                    <div data-role="collapsible">
                        <h2>Filtered list</h2>
                        <ul data-role="listview" data-filter-theme="c" data-divider-theme="d" data-inset="false">
                            <li><a href="index.html">Adam Kinkaid</a></li>
                            <li><a href="index.html">Alex Wickerham</a></li>
                            <li><a href="index.html">Avery Johnson</a></li>
                            <li><a href="index.html">Bob Cabot</a></li>
                            <li><a href="index.html">Caleb Booth</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="collapsible">
                        <h2>Formatted text</h2>
                        <ul data-role="listview" data-theme="d" data-divider-theme="d">
                            <li data-role="list-divider">Friday, October 8, 2010 <span class="ui-li-count">2</span></li>
                            <li><a href="index.html">
                                <h3>Stephen Weber</h3>
                                <p><strong>You've been invited to a meeting at Filament Group in Boston, MA</strong></p>
                                <p>Hey Stephen, if you're available at 10am tomorrow, we've got a meeting with the jQuery team.</p>
                                <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>6:24</strong>PM</p>
                                </a></li>
                            <li><a href="index.html">
                                <h3>jQuery Team</h3>
                                <p><strong>Boston Conference Planning</strong></p>
                                <p>In preparation for the upcoming conference in Boston, we need to start gathering a list of sponsors and speakers.</p>
                                <p class="ui-li-aside"><strong>9:18</strong>AM</p>
                                </a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div data-role="collapsible">
                        <h2>Thumbnails and split button</h2>
                        <ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="gear" data-split-theme="d" data-inset="false">
                            <li><a href="index.html">
                                <img src="../../_assets/img/album-bb.jpg">
                                    <h3>Broken Bells</h3>
                                    <p>Broken Bells</p>
                                </a><a href="lists-split-purchase.html" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="slideup">Purchase album
                                </a></li>
                                <li><a href="index.html">
                                    <img src="../../_assets/img/album-hc.jpg">
                                        <h3>Warning</h3>
                                        <p>Hot Chip</p>
                                    </a><a href="lists-split-purchase.html" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="slideup">Purchase album
                                    </a></li>
                                    <li><a href="index.html">
                                        <img src="../../_assets/img/album-p.jpg">
                                            <h3>Wolfgang Amadeus Phoenix</h3>
                                            <p>Phoenix</p>
                                        </a><a href="lists-split-purchase.html" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="slideup">Purchase album
                                        </a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>                
                        </div>
                    </div>    
                </body>
            </html>
```